# How to merge arrays passed to a function with variable parameters

Tags: c

Ive been researching all day on how to merge arrays, and make functions with variable parameters. Then it got me thinking, 'can't I combine the two?'. I came up with this function. According to my understanding it should work, but I'm getting errors. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

char* merge(int num, ...)
{
    va_list list;
    char arr[9] = {0};
    char *temp;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k=0;

    va_start(list,num);

    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        temp = va_arg(list,char[]);
        j = 0;
        while(temp[j] != 0x00)
        {
            arr[k] = temp[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    va_end(list);
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    char data_1[] = "my";
    char merged_array[9] = "legs";
    int n=0;

    //merged_array = merge(1,  data_1);
    while(merged_array == 0x00)
    {
        printf("%s\n",merged_array[n]);
        n++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think happens with `arr` when the function returns?

Comment: Afterall what is the need for variable parameters here? I guess you're experimenting with stdarg

Comment: @Olaf I think the address of arr gets passed to merged_array and arr is destroyed.

Comment: @Caleb: Exactly! And what do you think happens when you dereference that address (i.e. access the object that address points to) **after** the array has been destroyed?

Comment: @sjsam In my project i need to merge multiple arrays on different occasions, and I want to do it in one function. Otherwise I have to take the tedious route.

Comment: @Caleb: As you cannot dynamically create the argument list of a function, this is pretty useless anyway. Your code is confusing an error-prone, e.g. as you inhibit the compiler from checking types of arguments with varargs. Don't try getting too fancy and outwit yourself.

Comment: @Olaf whatever value at that address is passed on.

Comment: @Caleb: Please turn on your brain. You got all parts of the answer, just _think_ before you answer.

Comment: @Olaf thank you. Guess I have no choice but to go the tedious route.

Comment: @Caleb: If with "tedious" you mean thinking for yourself: Welcome to computer programming! You will not get any further in this field without. If that is not your's, programming is definitively not what you should do (nor is engineering). No offence, but a fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will help get you started:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

char* merge(char *arr, int num, ...)
   {
   va_list list;
   int i;

   va_start(list,num);
   for(i=0;i<num;i++)
      strcat(arr, va_arg(list,char *));
   va_end(list);

   return arr;
   }

int main()
   {
   char data_1[] = "my";
   char merged_array[9] = "legs";

   merge(merged_array, 1,  data_1);
   printf("%s\n", merged_array);

   return(0);
   }
```